# Blazor TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null at Object.e [as removeLogicalChild]

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I created a component for a dual list box. Everything is fine but when I submit I get an error.

```
 <EditForm Model="Model.Report" class="kt-form" OnValidSubmit="Model.OnSearch">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Columns</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <Project.Components.DualListbox ReportColumns="Model.Report.ReportColumns" Id="ReportColumns" @bind-Value="@Model.Report.ReportColumns"></Project.Components.DualListbox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" @onclick="Model.OnCloseModal"><i class="la la-close"></i> Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="la la-exchange"></i> Change</button>
                </div>
            </EditForm>
```

*`DualListbox` Razor code*:

```
@typeparam TValue
@inherits InputBase<TValue>


@if (ReportColumns != null)
{
    <select id="@Id" class="kt-dual-listbox" multiple>

        @foreach (var column in ReportColumns.OrderBy(c => c.Sort))
        {
            if (column.IsChecked == 1)
            {
                <option value="@column.Id" selected>@column.Title</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@column.Id">@column.Title</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
}
```

*`DualListbox` code-behind *:

```
using Project.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Project.Components
{
    public partial class DualListbox<TValue> : InputBase<TValue>
    {
        [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
        [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public ICollection<ReportColumn> ReportColumns { get; set; }

        public DotNetObjectReference<DualListbox<TValue>> DotNetRef;
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<object> OnChanged { get; set; }
        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string validationErrorMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == "null")
                {
                    value = null;
                }
                if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
                {
                    result = (TValue)(object)value;
                    validationErrorMessage = null;

                    return true;
                }
                else if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int) || typeof(TValue) == typeof(int?))
                {
                    int.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var parsedValue);
                    result = (TValue)(object)parsedValue;
                    validationErrorMessage = null;

                    return true;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} does not support the type '{typeof(TValue)}'.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            base.OnInitialized();
            DotNetRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        }

        protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
            if (firstRender)
            {
                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("dualListboxComponent.init", Id, DotNetRef, "Change_SelectWithFilterBase");
            }
        }

        [JSInvokable("Change_SelectWithFilterBase")]
        public void Change(string value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == "null")
                {
                    value = null;
                }

                var array = value.Split("#");
                if (array[0] == "add")
                {
                    int _value = int.Parse(array[1]);
                    var report = ReportColumns.Where(c => c.Id == _value).FirstOrDefault();
                    report.IsChecked = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    int _value = int.Parse(array[1]);
                    var report = ReportColumns.Where(c => c.Id == _value).FirstOrDefault();
                    report.IsChecked = 0;
                } 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            if (OnChanged.HasDelegate)
                OnChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
}
```

> [2020-02-12T07:42:28.867Z] Error: There was an error applying batch 7.
> e.log @ blazor.server.js:15 blazor.server.js:8 Uncaught (in promise)

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
> at Object.s [as insertLogicalChild] (blazor.server.js:8)
> at e.insertText (blazor.server.js:8)
> at e.insertFrame (blazor.server.js:8)
> at e.applyEdits (blazor.server.js:8)
> at e.updateComponent (blazor.server.js:8)
> at Object.t.renderBatch (blazor.server.js:1)
> at e. (blazor.server.js:15)
> at blazor.server.js:15
> at Object.next (blazor.server.js:15)
> at blazor.server.js:15 blazor.server.js:15 [2020-02-12T07:42:28.926Z] Error: System.AggregateException: One or
> more errors occurred. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore'
> of null)  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: TypeError: Cannot
> read property 'insertBefore' of null    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InvokeRenderCompletedCallsAfterUpdateDisplayTask(Task
> updateDisplayTask, Int32[] updatedComponents)    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 36):

My problem was in FontAwesome too. In my case, put icons inside `<span></span>` solved problems.

```
   @if (conditional)
            {
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
                </span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </span>
            }
```

Comment: This problem still exists today and this fixed it for me as well.  Thanks @Diego for sharing this fix.

Comment: @Diego Do you know whay that we have to repeat `<span>`  tag for each condition? becuase I tried to add one `tag` around the whole `if/else` and I got the same error!

Comment: You're a saviour, this is the exact problem I get every single time when I put a fontsawesome icon into an if statement.

Comment: Woo, what an ugly bug!  I am not sure how long it would have taken me to figure this one out as I had just done a massive refactor sweep and too many places to look.  Simple search landed on this.  Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me as well. This should be the accepted answer :D

Comment: I should have seen it earlier in my life :(. Lost quite a bit of time to find out it was fontawesome

Comment: Same here. Spent too much time for something so stupid....

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you. The issue is that FA modifies the physical DOM, and Blazor is then unable to locate the DOM node to be changed.

Comment: For anyone wondering why this happens in this specific case: When using Font Awesome's Javascript, it'll modify the DOM element that's at the top of your conditional fragment. When Blazor updates, it'll try to find this element which has been altered, and it'll break. By wrapping it in a `<span>` element, the root of your render fragment doesn't get modified, so Blazor will happily throw out everything that's inside of it, whether it was changed or not.

Answer (score 17):

So, this may not be your exact answer, but it may give a clue to someone who stumbles upon this SO question.  In my case, this was the result of swapping out a Font Awesome icon within button text as opposed to using two separate buttons.

This may be related because you are using the JSRuntime in combination with "report.IsChecked = 1;" syntax, which I assume is changing UI element state client-side that Blazor Server is trying to (but unable) to track.

When I used conditional logic within a single button to swap out the icon, I received an error, "blazor TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null".  **This syntax using two separate buttons, however, worked just fine:**

```
@if (AllowAllPartners)
{
    <button @onclick="(() => AllowAllPartnersToggle())">
        <i class="far fa-check-square"></i>
    </button>
}
else
{
    <button @onclick="(() => AllowAllPartnersToggle())">
        <i class="far fa-square"></i>
    </button>
}
```

Comment: Exactly same issue with font awesome icons changing on run-time. Also exactly same icon. Let me know if you found not so nasty solution.

Comment: ah, it's totally the font-awesome svg icons. they've replaced the rendered icons in the dom.

Comment: you are a legend

Answer (score 9):

In my case the same error was caused by my use of Bootstrap Dismissible Alerts, containing a MatBlazor component, and/or FontAwesome icon.

Placing the alert inside another `<div></div>` solved this issue.  Placing the icon/component within the alert inside `<span></span>` did not work, but I found this solution thanks to Diego's suggestion :-)

```
   <div>
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          Warning Text <MatTooltip Tooltip="Tooltip text" Context="_context1" Wrap="true" Position="@MatTooltipPosition.Top"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i></MatTooltip>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I was not using the MatBlazor component or a FontAwesome icon but *was* tyrying to implement a dismissible alert onto the top of a razor page for a blazor web assembly project. Adding it into the div worked without issue. Thank you!